# What happens when there are duplicate keys in Java properties file?

Tags: java, properties, configuration

What is the defined behaviour when there are duplicate keys in a Java `.properties` file?

```
thing.valueA = 1
thing.valueB = 2

thing.valueA = 99
```

Which value is guaranteed to be used for `thing.valueA`? 1, 99, or undefined? Is this behaviour documented anywhere?

NB. I am not asking whether duplicate keys are considered best practice.

Comment: The official Java 6 docs seem to be conspicuously missing any mention of duplicate keys... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because this isn't defined in the spec for the class, I'd say the most correct answer to this question is that the result is undefined, and could vary from implementation to implementation.

However, because java.util.Properties inherits from java.utils.Hashtable, the most likely implementation is exactly as described by @jozefg, and you can see in the OpenJDK source that the Sun implementation works that way ([Properties.java:345](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Properties.java) as of the time of this writing). Read each line, parse it to decide if you need to append other lines, separate key and value, put key/value in Hashtable.

There's no:

- check to see if the key exists
- exception thrown based on the presence of the key
- avoidance of overwriting values
- out-of-order processing

It's all very simple and basically assumes either that you haven't used duplicate keys, or that if you have, it's your problem to sort out.

Now, of course, to be totally sure you'd want to look at all the likely JVMs or at least the target JVM for your code to make sure the implementation doesn't differ, but I think this implementation is the most likely one.

Comment: This question was old when I got to it, but I was curious what the answer was, and since none of the answers referred to the actual implementation, it seemed worth checking, and having done so, recording the answer for the next person who comes by.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer your answer, because it acknowledges that duplicate behaviour is undefined, but that because of implementation (and start-to-finish reading of the file), the behaviour of duplicates can be pretty reliable in practice. Cheers.

Answer (score 13):

Based on my understanding of `Properties`, the load method works in a similar fashion to this:

1. Split the file into lines,
2. Look at the next line,
3. Determine the Key-Value pair using some rules (See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29))
4. Put the key value pair into the Properties instance in a fashion similar to the `put()` method

This would mean that your example would display `99`.

The load method is basically designed to work as though you had sat down and typed out

```
propInstance.put("Key", "Value");
propInstance.put("Other", "Thing");
etc etc
```

To understand this behavior, see the documentation for `Hashtable.put()` which specifies that it updates any duplicates with the new value. Since Hashtable is the superclass for Properties, Properties also replicates this behaviour.

Comment: That's helpful and insightful, jozefg. I was hoping for something a little more direct and definitive, but this is great! Reasonably, this answer assumes that the properties file is read in-order from beginning to end. I'm happy to live with that assumption...

Comment: @aaaidan edited it to make it a little less verbose and more clear

Comment: I think I actually preferred your previous answer, but okay! The part about Properties inheriting from HashTable was helpful for me to accept that this behaviour is probably consistent (because it would be crazy to think that the `Reader` would traverse the list in any way except top-to-bottom).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.  Instead of using Properties, I instantiated a NaehasProperties, and overrode the HashTable put().

```
/**
 *  Purpose:  Properties doesn't detect duplicate keys.  So this exists.
 *  @author shaned
 */
package com.naehas.tests.configs;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class NaehasProperties extends Properties
{
   private static final long   serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private static final Logger log              = Logger.getLogger(NaehasProperties.class);

   public NaehasProperties()
   {
      super();
   }

   /**
    * @param defaults
    */
   public NaehasProperties(Properties defaults)
   {
      super(defaults);
   }

   /**
    * Overriding the HastTable put() so we can check for duplicates
    * 
    */
   public synchronized Object put(Object key, Object value)
   {
      // Have we seen this key before?
      //
      if (get(key) != null)
      {
         StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer("Duplicate key found: " + key + " with value: " + value);
         message.append(". Original value is: " + (String) get(key));

         log.error(message.toString());

         // Setting key to null will generate an exception and cause an exit.
         // Can not change the signature by adding a throws as it's not compatible
         // with HashTables put().
         //
         key = null;
      }

      return super.put(key, value);
   }
}
```

Comment: That's an excellent way to dissect the current implementation. What I wanted to know was whether the override behaviour is _specified_ or not. In other words, can I bank on it always behaving this way, or might a future implementation of Java change this?

Comment: *"Setting key to `null` will generate an exception and cause an exit. Cannot change the signature by adding a `throws` as it's not compatible with HashTable's `put()`"* Actually, you can throw `RuntimeException` or any of its subclass, if you really need to throw an exception without adding a `throws`. I particularly like `IllegalStateException` and `IllegalArgumentException` but in this case, `UnsupportedOperationException` or `ArrayStoreException` may be a better fit [go with `java.lang` package].

Comment: For use in unit tests, I don't set the key to null or throw an exception. Instead I save the key in a `duplicateKeys` Collection of Strings. Then the unit test can test that this is empty and also get the names of all duplicate keys. If an exception is thrown then processing of the unit test will probably stop and you'll only get the _first_ duplicate key.

Answer (score 0):

It usually takes the last value,in your case it will be 99.

Thanks,
Raghavan

Comment: The "usually" part is the problem... I was asking whether I can guarantee that this will always be the case. Thanks!